# When is "Thanks Be to God" said in the mass?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy, mass

When do we say "Thanks be to God" in the mass, is it in the Liturgy of the Word? Also when do we say "Praise to You Lord Jesus Christ" in the mass, is it after the Gospel?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only mention the mass and not a denomination, I'll assume you mean in the Catholic Church. However, the same will apply for most liturgical traditions

After each of the first (often Old Testament) and second ( New Testament)  lessons, the reader will say

> The word of the Lord

to which the people respond

> Thanks be to God.

The Gospel reading is announced by

> A reading from the holy Gospel according to N.

The people respond

> Glory to you, Lord.

After the Gospel reading, the reader says

> The Gospel of the Lord.

The people respond

> Praise to you, Lord Jesus Christ

At the end of the mass, the people are dismissed with (or something similar)

> Go forth, the Mass is ended

And again the people respond

> Thanks be to God

Comment: Is the source for this [the Roman Missal](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_20030317_ordinamento-messale_en.html)?

Comment: Don't forget the deacon processing in with the Easter candle on Holy Saturday! "Christ our Light!" "Thanks be to God!"

Answer (score 0):

In the offices of Matins Vespers and other hours (e.g., Lauds) in the extraordinary form, the Latin equivalent of "Thanks be to God" — "Deo Gratias" after the lessons, after the chapter, and after the concluding "Bendicamus Domino" [Let us bless the Lord].  Some of these responses are part of the Liturgy of the Word, the response to the Benedicamus Domino is part of the dismissal.